# The separation of the subset $[-1, 0) \cup (0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ contains the limit point of the other

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In the book of *Topology* by Munkres, it is given at page 149 that

[image]

[image]

However, what does the author mean by the fact that $0$ is the common limit point of the two open sets in $Y$ does not matter ?, and how can this be ? I mean isn't this a contradiction to lemma 23.1 ?

Comment: The statement means that no point in $A$ can be the limit point of $B$ and vice-versa. $0$ is a limit point of both $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$, but it is not contained in either set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=[-1,0)$, $0$ is a limit point of $A$, but $B=(0,1]$ does not contain the limit point: $0\notin B$.

Similarly, $0$ is a limit point of $B$, but $A$ does not contain it.

No contradiction is involved.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.